# Rack-timeout results in 500 instead of 503

Tags: heroku, exception, ruby-on-rails-4.2, timeoutexception, rollbar

I'm using heroku's [`rack-timeout`](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout) gem, along with dynamic error pages as described [here](https://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails).

However, when timeout raises an exception, it get's routed as a 500 error rather than 503.

I could catch the exception with a `rescue_from` in my application controller and manually route to errors#503, but that would prevent plugins like Rollbar from recording the exception.

Is there a way to get the correct error page rendered and ensure plugins like Rollbar still get wind of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [`rambulance`](https://github.com/yuki24/rambulance) gem, which provides a simple configuration option to solve this:

```
# config/initializers/rambulance.rb

Rambulance.setup do |config|
  config.rescue_responses = {
    "Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException" => :service_unavailable
  }
end
```

The author has also written up some good reasons why not to use the approach I was previously using:

[Remove custom errors page section from the guides](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17815)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there's  no need to add a gem dependency for this.

rack-timeout raises an exception; **the 500 results from that exception being unhandled**. To handle that exception and get a 503 or whatever else you might want, add:

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses["Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException"] = :service_unavailable
```

to your application.rb file.